# SQL Server 2014 - Windows Installer error message: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am trying to install SQL server 2014 Express on a windows 7 PC for 2 days now. I re-installed then installed SQL Server 2014 several times but I keep getting the same window installer error message
I keep getting the following errors here's the full log:

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered an error when running a Windows Installer file.
```

Windows Installer error message: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007054F. Windows Installer file: C:\Users\Receno\AppData\Local\Temp\SQL Server 2012\Setup\1033_ENU_LP\x64\setup\sqlsupport_msi\SqlSupport.msi Windows Installer log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150109_213740\SqlSupport_Cpu64_1_ComponentUpdate_1.log

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0xDC80C325

Comment: So did you click the link that it told you to click *For help*? You've even managed to copy and paste it here, but did you go there to see what it said?

Comment: Are you installing the 64 bit version of SQL Server Express or the 32bit? Is your OS 64 bit? Have you install Windows 7 SP1?

Comment: The link is dead. So unless its in the Wayback Machine, there is no telling what it says.

Comment: I've been getting the identical error for a couple of days now, installing SQL Server 2012 Express 64 (x64) on a Windows 7 64 bit OS. The issue seems to be that the installer needs the Microsoft.VB80.ATL assembly (and its depend Visual C 2005 assemblies) installed and in place in the WinSxS directory, and it isn't there. However, the install inspector believes it is there, so it lets you try to install. It seems that an old version of .Net 2 is being sought, but isn't available, and the OS thinks .Net 2 is installed (it is actually 3.5.1 on my W7 machine).

Comment: @StarPilot - so is the solution to install .NET 2?